# How to create a MultiPolygon in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

How can I create a MultiPolygon in Cesium?
Not a polygon with a hole, but 2 or more polygons as 1 object.
Now I use:

```
    var object = map.entities.add({
        polygon : {hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(pathArray),
    etc..
```

For a single Polygon the pathArray is like [x1,y1,x2,x2,x3,y3,x4,y4,...]

For MultiPolygon I expected a nested array like [[path1],[path2],[path3]] but this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Cesium does not currently have support for a multipolygon.  You need to add a new entity for each.
You can use a parent entity if you wanted to change things like the 'show' property of a group of entities.  You can see an example of how to do this here: http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Show%20or%20Hide%20Entities.html&label=Beginner